# TextView does not appear when added dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I am dynamically adding a TextView which does not appear, what seems to be the problem?

Is there a difference between following two lines:

```
 receiptLayout.addView(order_1_confirm);

 ((LinearLayout) receiptLayout).addView(order_1_confirm);
```

Well, neither one of them does not work!

My activity_receipt.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/receiptMainLinearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view_rsc_logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/rsc_logo"
    android:src="@drawable/rsc" />
```

and my ReceiptActivity.java:

```
public class ReceiptActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_receipt);

    LinearLayout receiptLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.receiptMainLinearLayout);
    TextView order_1_confirm = new TextView(this);
    order_1_confirm.setText("hello");

            //receiptLayout.addView(order_1_confirm);
    ((LinearLayout) receiptLayout).addView(order_1_confirm);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give  `android:orientation="vertical"` in your `LinearLayout`.

And in

```
 LinearLayout receiptLayout = (`LinearLayout`)findViewById(R.id.receiptMainLinearLayout);
```

you are already casting view to LinearLayout  so no need to cast it again

Answer (score 0):

Set the size and color of the `TextView`. Perhaps it seems invisible because it is the same color as the background.

Answer (score 0):

you should always add orientation to the `LinearLayout`, adding `android:orientation="vertical"` would works fine.